# Inserting a footer into HTML using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have written the CSS code for my footer:

```
#footer{
position:fixed;
left:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
vertical-align:bottom;
bottom:0px;
width:100%;
height:25px;
background-color:#4A6181;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

And I have called the stylesheet in my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://angrysheep.zxq.net/footer.css" type="text/css" />
```

But, how do I actually put the footer into my webpage? What HTML code should I use to add it into the page?

Comment: I would focus on fixing your existing markup first, you have some pretty serious errors. Use the validation tool for guidance: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fangrysheep.zxq.net By the way, you typically don't need different CSS files for each element in your markup, just one CSS file is usually fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for markup,

```
<div id='footer'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

inside the wrapper, but at the end, add your `<div id="footer"></div>`